# Customize Ctrl+C behavior in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, copy-paste

I am using a WPF `DataGrid` to display name-value pairs. `SelectionUnit` is set to `FullRow` because it looks nice, however, when user selects a row and presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> he really wants to copy the value text rather than the default behavior which is a concatenation of name and value. When looking for solution I found `CopyingRowClipboardContent` event but [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.copyingrowclipboardcontent.aspx) has no information about how to use it. Or should I capture `PreviewKeyDown` myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the copied data in the `CopyingRowClipboardContent` event handler using the `DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs`.

Decompiled source code

```
public class DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This list should be used to modify, add or remove a cell
    /// content before it gets stored into the clipboard.
    /// </summary> 
    public List<DataGridClipboardCellContent> ClipboardRowContent
    { 
       ...
```

So for example, if you have two columns and you only want the first, you can remove the second item like this:

```
private void grid_CopyingRowClipboardContent(
    object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    e.ClipboardRowContent.RemoveAt(1);
}
```

Comment: This only overrides the copied text for each row, I came here looking for how to override the actual command binding so the datagrid's implementation is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's what you're looking for

`ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.ExcludeHeader;`

Comment: No, that's to exclude column header and what I want is to exclude certain cells in the row.